# Обработка таблиц SQLite в python

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite

У меня есть таблица

| id | friends |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | [1, 4] |
| 4 | [1, 2] |

моя задача - построить все связи друзей пользователей.

Если friends - NULL, то перебираем все остальные ID.
И ищем, у кого этот ID является другом.

Идентификатор с номером 1 - NULL.
С помощью скрипта ищем, у кого в друзьях есть 1.
Это идентификаторы под номерами 3 и 4.
Итак, запоминаем 3 и 4, после того как пройдете все строки - сохраняем этот массив в friends к id 1.
И так далее с каждой строкой.

Итак, я должен определить, какие ID являются друзьями искомого ID.
После определения у меня будет массив, тот самый массив, который я пишу вместо NULL.

Таким образом, я должен получить:

| id | friends |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [3, 4] |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | [1, 4] |
| 4 | [1, 2] |

Но если это не NULL, то все равно нужно пройтись по всем пользователям и записать, есть ли изменения.

У идентификатора 4 есть такой список [1, 2].
Но у ID 3 есть пользователь 4 ([1, 4]).
Поэтому я добавляю 4 к существующему списку.

Вот что было:
[1, 2]

А вот как должно быть:
[1, 2, 3]

(Важно, необходимо выполнить .sort())

Что я сделал.

```
for row in cursor:
    id = row[0]
    friends = row[1]
    print(id, friends)
    if friends == None:
        new_friends = []
        for row in cursor:
            fr_id = row[0]
            str_fr_friends = row[1]
            if str_fr_friends != None:
                fr_id = row[0]
                str_fr_friends = row[1]
                fr_friends = json.loads(str_fr_friends)
                # print(fr_id, fr_friends)
                if fr_id not in new_friends:
                    if id in fr_friends:
                        new_friends.append(fr_id)
                        print(id, new_friends)
                        # print(fr_id, fr_friends) 
        new_friends = json.dumps(new_friends)
        if new_friends != []:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE Users SET friends = ? WHERE id = ?", (new_friends, id))
```

Я решил начать обработку с тех случаев, когда friends является NULL.

Проблема в том, что код редактирует только 1-ю строку. Если я запускаю его снова, то он переходит ко второй строке.

Я добавил часть для обработки случаев, когда friends не NULL, но это только ухудшило ситуацию.

ВОПРОС: Как заставить скрипт редактировать каждую строку?

моя база данных состоит из 850 000 000 строк, поэтому я читаю ее построчно. Возможно, мне следует использовать другой способ чтения, но загрузить ее полностью в файл определенно невозможно

Comment: Вопрос про SQLite. Но в приведённом тексте программы нет ни одного оператора, связанного с SQLite. В чём, на самом деле, заключается Ваш вопрос? И второе замечание. "Таблица", приведённая в самом начале описания задачи, таблицей в смысле любого SQL (не только SQLite) не является. Она нарушает сразу два условия первой нормальной формы: данные одной колонки разного типа; данные не элементарны. Переформулируйте условие вопроса.

Comment: Мне нужно обновить списки друзей на основе других данных из таблицы. Я написал свой код но он работает не корректно. Я ищу способ как можно решить эту проблему. Либо модифицировать свой код либо написать иное решение

Answer (score 1):

Это вполне можно и нужно делать одним sql-запросом update.

```sql
update foo
set friends = (
    select (
        select '[' || group_concat(f2.id) || ']'
        from foo f2, json_each(friends)
        where f1.id = json_each.value
        group by json_each.value
    )
    from foo f1
    where foo.id = f1.id
)
where friends is null;
```

Этот запрос отрабатывает на показанных четырёх строках.
`foo` - имя таблицы.
Используются [JSON Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jtype).

---

При изменении большого количества строк следует обновить статистику: [ANALYZE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html)